# Using jsPlumb with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsplumb

I am rendering some elements from react and connecting using jsPlumb. Every time there is a change in the config I am reconnecting the nodes.
But I get errors from jsPlumb starting from the second rendering like

`.each iteration failed : TypeError: Cannot read property 'force' of undefined`

Then all drag/move interaction from jsplumb stops working with errors.

What would be the best way to reset jsPlumb instance with removing all endpoint references and connections? I am doing jsPlumbInstance.reset() but its not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is I use a component for each edge that just renders an empty div and pass the edge info and jsplumb instance in through the props. Then the parent component keeps track of what edges are connected.

In the parent class:

```
var edgeComponents = []
validEdges.forEach(     
  edge => {     
    edgeComponents.push(     
      <Edge
        key={${edge.source}-${edge.target}}     
        edge={edge}     
        jsPlumb={this.state.jsPlumbInstance}     
      /> )
  }
)
```

The child class:

```
export default class Edge extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    const edge = this.props.edge
    const connection = this.props.jsPlumb.connect({source:edge.source, target:edge.target})
    this.setState({connection: connection})
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.props.jsPlumb.detach(this.state.connection)
  }
}
```

Comment: I am doing the same but before `connect` call I also need to do `addEndpoint` or `makeSource`/`makeTarget` or any other way of setting up the connectors, if I am not wrong. And as my elements potentially can change every time the component mounts, I need to do and undo that every time. I think thats where my errors come in. So am I doing it wrong?

Comment: My endpoints are static and attached to my node component so I don't have to worry about that, but I imagine you could create them and destroy them in the same way if you want them to be part of the edges. My edges use a key based on the uuids of the endpoints. The parent component just keeps track of which edge components to render and if one disappears it is unmounted.